# Relationships in EF 6 code first, what is mandatory, what is optional and why?

Tags: database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I'm new to the Entity Framework and I've been reading the [asp.net EF 6 using MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and other webpages for a few days but I'm confused and a bit lost understanding how these relationships in EF 6 (code first) work.

I don't understand for every kind of relationship (1:1, 1:n, n:n), what is optional and what is mandatory? For example, the asp.net website say you have to have foreign keys and navigation properties for for this kind of relationship and what not but the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee382841(v=vs.100).aspx) for the navigation property say, they are optional. (Is it so that navigation properties are optional in general but for the code first workflow they are necessary?)

So what would be really really nice of you is to draw a table and tell me for each kind of relationship, how do you define it in EF 6 code first, what is mandatory, what is optional and what is the benefit of this optional item (I can't believe such basic thing doesn't exist/hard to find in the net). If you could also send a reference where I can learn more about the EF 6 code first (that is not so long) it would be great too.

Comment: I guess I mostly get your question, but the only real issue is I've having is that EF doesn't *require* anything, that is to say that what is required/optional is really a business decision and not a technology decision.  If you're just trying to understand the concepts of entity framework, then this question is more suited to [programmers.stackexchange.com -  is a question and answer site for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: What I would suggest is to build a very simple example of something you are trying to model, and if it does not work, then you should post that specific coding question here.  As your question stands, it appears you are just asking for example code which is off-topic for SO.

Comment: It's not even an Entity Framework question. This is just basic Object relationships. Two objects are related. Should they be a 1:1, 1:n, *:n? Why?

Answer (score 2):

The msdn link states that

> you do not have to define a navigation property on the entity type at
>   the **other end** of the association.

This means that you can create a 1:n relation

```
public class EntityA
{
    public virtual ICollection<EntityB> EntityBs { get; set; }
}
```

without having to create a navigation property on EntityB that points to EntityA.

I think it is best to be explicit with the relations so that you communicate your intent in code. I do this by specifying the relationships in OnModelCreating method in the context class.

```
public class Context : DbContext 
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
    }
}
```

In this case, the relationships (between entity EntityA and EntityB) you ask to be specified becomes:

**1:1**
Note that this will create the db relation by syncing the primary key instead of using a foreign key

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.EntityB)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.EntityA);
```

**0..1:n**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityB>().HasOptional(x => x.EntityA).WithMany();
```

**1:n**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityB>().HasRequired(x => x.EntityA).WithMany();
```

**n:m**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityB>().HasMany(x => x.EntityA).WithMany(x => x.EntityB);
```